# Chunking HTTP replies with RESTAS

Tags: http, http-headers, common-lisp, hunchentoot

Lets say that I would like to send a rather large file (10MB for example) and that I would like to do this with HTTP1.1 chunked transfer encoding. How would I do this in RESTAS?

Comment: you need to set `acceptor-output-chunking-p` on the appropriate `HUNCHENTOOT` acceptor

Comment: Yes, I did figure that out. The problem is that RESTAS does not define acceptors, it defines routes (which gets expanded into a defun). Basically: Where are the acceptors?

Comment: I think, you can get it from request object with `hunchentoot:request-acceptor`

Comment: Hm, yeah, I got a weird error when I tried that... Gonna post the error as soon as possible.